# A perl expression to grep until the appearance of one character combination

Tags: regex, perl, unix, grep

I have a very long string with this pattern:

```
34>>>Tamal234659 new tamal thing:01:34775 more tamal, for more tamal. etc...etc...etc...etc... 35>>>Tamal572934 old tamal thing:4c:33475 more tamal, for more tamal07. etc...etc...etc...etc... 35
```

I want to grep everything from the %d%d>>> until another  %d%d>>> appears.

Like the \K trick but instead of forgetting the beginning, forgetting the ending.

Comment: Do you only want to get one result, or do you want to get multiple results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the following:

Input:

```
my @input =('34>>>Tamal234659 new tamal thing:01:34775 more tamal, for more tamal. etc...etc...etc...etc...35>>>Tamal572934 old tamal thing:4c:33475 more tamal, for more tamal07. etc...etc...etc...etc... 35');

my @lines;
foreach (@input){
    my @capture = ( $_ =~ /(\d+>>>.+)/g);
    push @lines, @capture;
}
```

Comment: It work really good, but I just found out that my idea was wrong, lol.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'print $2 if(/([\d]+)\>\>\>(.*) ([\d]+)\>\>\>.*/)' your_file
```

tested:

```
> cat temp
34>>>Tamal234659 new tamal thing:01:34775 more tamal, for more tamal. etc...etc...etc...etc... 35>>>Tamal572934 old tamal thing:4c:33475 more tamal, for more tamal07. etc...etc...etc...etc... 35

> perl -lne 'print $2 if(/([\d]+)\>\>\>(.*) ([\d]+)\>\>\>.*/)' temp
Tamal234659 new tamal thing:01:34775 more tamal, for more tamal. etc...etc...etc...etc...
>
```